# C#/-MVC : filename for export excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filenames, export-to-excel

I have ​​an export excel file from my MVC application.
The export works but I am having difficulties to give the name of the Excel file for the selection of a list in a dropdown.
The user selects the name of a company and then performs the export of Excel. I wish I could give the name of the company chosen to Excel but I do not see how to do it.

```
public class BLConstants
{
    public static readonly string DashboardCookieName = "dashboard-filters";
    public static readonly string EnumResourcePrefix = "ENUM_";

    public static readonly int RecentDaysCount = 30;

    public static readonly int Minimal_Score = 13;

    public static readonly int Control_Default_ControlAction = 2;
    public static readonly int Control_Default_Sensitivity = 3;
    public static readonly int Control_Default_Status = 3;
    public static readonly int Control_Default_Frequency = 4;
    public static readonly int Control_Default_ControlState = 1;

    public static readonly int CompliancePercentage_Good = 100;
    public static readonly int CompliancePercentage_Average = 54;
    public static readonly int CompliancePercentage_Bad = 13;
    public static readonly int CompliancePercentage_NotApplicable = 0;

    #region Mappings

    public static readonly string GoodLetter = "J";
    public static readonly string AverageLetter = "K";
    public static readonly string BadLetter = "L";

    public static readonly Dictionary<string, Frequencies> FrequenciesMapping = new Dictionary<string, Frequencies>
        {
            {"Monthly", Frequencies.Monthly},
            {"Quarterly", Frequencies.Quarterly},
            {"Semi-annually", Frequencies.BiAnnualy},
            {"Yearly", Frequencies.Yearly}
        };

    public static readonly Dictionary<string, Sensitivities> SensitivitiesMapping = new Dictionary<string, Sensitivities>
        {
            {"HIGH", Sensitivities.High},
            {"MEDIUM", Sensitivities.Medium},
            {"LOW", Sensitivities.Low}
        };

    public static readonly Dictionary<string, Statuses> StatusesMapping = new Dictionary<string, Statuses>
        {
            {"J", Statuses.Good},
            {"K", Statuses.Average},
            {"L", Statuses.Bad},
            {"NA", Statuses.NotApplicable}
        };

    #endregion

    public static readonly int MaxCalendarMonthsBeforeNow = 11;    //Max : 23

    public static readonly string Reset_Password_Status = "InitPassword";

    public static readonly string HelpFilePath = "~/Content/Documents";
    public static readonly string HelpFileContentType = "application/pdf";

    public static readonly int ControlFirstDataLine = 4;
    public static readonly string ControlTemplate = "~/Content/Documents/ControlTemplate.xlsx";
    public static readonly string ControlTemplateContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.12";
    public static readonly string ControlTemplateFileName = "Controls.xlsx";      

    public static readonly int RegulationFirstDataLine = 4;
    public static readonly string RegulationTemplate = "~/Content/Documents/RegulationTemplate.xlsx";
    public static readonly string RegulationTemplateContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.12";
    public static readonly string RegulationTemplateFileName = "Regulations.xlsx";

    public static readonly string ExcelFrenchUrlValue = "French";
    public static readonly string ExcelEnglishUrlValue = "English";

}
```

This is the part I'd like to change:

```
public static readonly string ControlTemplateFileName = "Controls.xlsx";
```

I have a list of company, and I would like the name of my excel file exported matches the name of the selected company.

For the dropdown :

```
<select>
  <label for="companySelect">ADMIN_CTRL_EXPORT_COMPANY</label>
  <select id="SelectedCompany" class="ui-state-valid" name="SelectedCompany">
    <option>Select a company</option>
    <option value="1">Company1</option>
    <option value="2">Company2</option>
    <option value="3">Company3</option>
  </select>
</select>
```

What is the best way to implement this ?

For the export Excel :

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public FileStreamResult _ControlsExport(ControlsExportModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                //TODO
                return null;

            LoggingService.Write(string.Format("Exporting the controls for the company ID: {0}", model.SelectedCompany));

            int parsedId;
            if (!int.TryParse(model.SelectedCompany, out parsedId))
                throw new ArgumentException("model.SelectedCompany is not an int.");

            var data = ContextDataService.GetModuleExportData(parsedId);
            var stream = ExcelService.ExportModule(data);

            return File(stream, BLConstants.ControlTemplateContentType, BLConstants.ControlTemplateFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error in AdminController._ControlsExport(ControlsExportModel model)", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One issue is that it's a readonly field. A quick fix may be to make a method to set the value, and make it not readonly. It's difficult to comment without seeing where the excel sheet export code is actually called from

Comment: I've edited for the the excel sheet export code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so remove the reference to BLConstants.ControlTemplateFileName in the return line, and replace it with a string from (I assume) the var data, with .xlsx at the end? like data.CompanyName + ".xlsx" perhaps?

The assumption I have made is that var data contains information about the company

If this method is re-used to export other data types though, you will need to take that into account and append the file type according to what is being exported

e.g. data.CompanyName + exportTypeExtension

Comment: Thanks ! I look on this side, but I had little problems ... I tjs an export. "Xlsx". It fails to recognize the CompanyName.